# x509.DecryptPEMBlock Deprecated

Tags: go

in go 1.16.3
this func "x509.DecryptPEMBlock" is Deprecated

comments from go source

Deprecated: Legacy PEM encryption as specified in RFC 1423 is insecure by
design. Since it does not authenticate the ciphertext, it is vulnerable to
padding oracle attacks that can let an attacker recover the plaintext.

which func or what to use instead of "x509.DecryptPEMBlock" ?

Comment: There is no alternative if you have to process keymaterial that has been encrypted as specified by RFC 1423.

Comment: you mean there is not any alternative to set a password on privateKey file and read in golang. don't you? so what do others (such as microsoft in DotNet Core) do?

Comment: The recommended alternative to the deprecated "x509.DecryptPEMBlock" function is to use encryption algorithms that provide authentication, such as AES in Galois/Counter Mode (GCM). You can also use a library that provides a secure implementation of encryption and decryption, such as the Go standard library's "crypto/tls" package.

Comment: Check out the discussion at Github on Go's issue list #8860: crypto/x509: no support for parsing encrypted PKCS8 private keys at https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8860.

Comment: Some projects include old copies of this x509 package with this functions, you can find those at https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=DecryptPEMBlock , didn't tested but some of those should work. (Keep in mind, what you are doing is not safe).