# "x509.DecryptPEMBlock" is Deprecated, what is alternative?

Tags: go, cryptography

As of Go 1.16, `x509.Encrypt/DecryptPEMBlock` is Deprecated. What is the alternative for this to encrypt private key?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432235/x509-decryptpemblock-deprecated

Comment: @Peter: the question is indeed a duplicate, but the linked question doesn't even have an answer. It'd be great to expand upon your comment to an answer which could then be marked accepted and used as a canonical link to further deprecated questions

Comment: There are alternatives, but requests for recommendations are off-topic for SO. One common format is encrypted [PKCS8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5208), though Go does not currently support decrypting these with the stand library: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8860.

Comment: These are deprecated due to the padding oracle attacks so there will be no std lib alternative as the intention is for the user to move away from this approach to another one. Read more here - https://github.com/golang/go/issues/59961 .

Answer (score 0):

I would use x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey and x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey for this purpose.

```
func ParsePrivateKey(data []byte) (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    return x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(data)
}

func MarshalPrivateKey(key *rsa.PrivateKey) []byte {
    data := x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key)
    return data
}
```